# Edit Git alias in command line

Tags: git, bash, alias

I am using Git for windows.

Right after installation, I setup some Git alias on Git bash command line. I used:
`git config --global alias.st status`

But now, I want to change the alias to diff --stat. Then, on Git bash, I typed `git config --global alias.st diff --stat`, but it seems to not replace the alias previously set. When I type `git st` it is still running `git status`.
Of course, I can go to the gitconfig file and edit it, but I want to make the change using the command line.

So, is there a way to replace an alias?

Comment: You need to quote the alias: `git config --global alias.st "diff --stat"` or the `--stat` will be considered an option to `git config`, not to `diff`. I'm not sure if this would produce the problem you describe.

Comment: @meagar You are correct. Quoting solved the problem. Dumb me. Just had to add --replace-all as Git warned!

Comment: @meagar Do you want to add a answer so I can mark it as correct? My mistake was that `status` didn't need quotes because it is only one word. When I copy&pasted it I didn't realized that it would need to be quoted for a more complex alias.

Comment: I'm not satisfied that I know what is going on; I was unaware that you could somehow supply duplicate aliases. I don't have time to investigate right now, but I will, and I'll post an answer if another one doesn't turn up in the mean time.

Comment: @meagar Yeah, git lets you specify multiple values for config options. It's part of the [INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Duplicate_names) that git uses for its config files. I posted an explanation in my answer below in case you're interested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with any other config option you can set the value, replacing the old one, by running `git config --global alias.st <value here>`. The problem you're running into is that when you want spaces in the value you're setting, you need to use quotes:

```
git config --global alias.st "diff --stat"
```

Unfortunately, if you've already tried running without quotes you may have triggered a different problem as well. Have a look at this bit from the [documentation for `git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> 'git config' name [value [value_regex]]
> ```

Notice that bit there called `value_regex`? Since you didn't quote your previous command, `diff` got interpreted as the `value`, and `--stat` got interpreted as the `value_regex`. What does that do? Well...

> Multiple lines can be added to an option by using the --add option. If
>   you want to update or unset an option which can occur on multiple
>   lines, a POSIX regexp value_regex needs to be given. Only the existing
>   values that match the regexp are updated or unset.

So what happened is that git tried to update the config option `alias.st` that already had the value `--stat`. Since no such config line existed, git created a *second* config line for `alias.st`. You can confirm this by running:

```
git config --global --get-all alias.st
```

Which should show two values for `alias.st`. To fix this, you should run:

```
git config --global --replace-all alias.st "diff --stat"
```

Which should get you back to having one config line for `alias.st`, and fix your problem for good.